# How to count the change of event (0 to 1) based on a column in dataframe for each unique id

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am looking to generate a new column col2 by counting the number of events in column 1 such that whenever column1 state changes from 0 to 1 for each unique id, The count increments by 1 and the incremented value is recorded in the new column. below is the sample of the desired output.

df:

```
Id Period Col1 col2(Out)
1 Jan-21   0     0
1 Feb-21   1     1
1 Mar-21   0     1
1 Apr-21   0     1
1 May-21   1     2
1 Jun-21   0     2
1 Jul-21   1     3
1 Aug-21   1     3
1 Sep-21   0     3
1 Oct-21   1     4
2 Jan-21   1     0
2 Feb-21   1     0
2 Mar-21   0     0
2 Apr-21   1     1
2 May-21   0     1
2 Jun-21   1     2
2 Jul-21   0     2
2 Jun-21   0     2
2 Jul-21   1     3
2 Aug-21   0     3
2 Sep-21   0     3
3 Jan-21   1     0
3 Feb-21   1     0
3 Mar-21   0     0
3 Apr-21   1     1
3 May-21   0     1
3 Jun-21   0     1
3 Jul-21   0     1
3 Aug-21   1     2
3 Sep-21   0     2
```

I am able to get the total count for each unique id but not able to update the new column with incremneted value   based on state change from 0 to 1.  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done [any research work](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+count+events)?

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
# assuming the values are only 0/1
df['Col2'] = (df.groupby('Id')['Col1']
                .transform(lambda s: s.diff().eq(1).cumsum())
             )
```

Or, less efficient but maybe easier to adapt, with a double [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
df['Col2'] = ((df['Col1'].eq(1) & df.groupby('Id')['Col1'].shift().eq(0))
              .groupby(df['Id']).cumsum()
             )
```

Output:

```
    Id  Period  Col1  col2(Out)  Col2
0    1  Jan-21     0          0     0
1    1  Feb-21     1          1     1
2    1  Mar-21     0          1     1
3    1  Apr-21     0          1     1
4    1  May-21     1          2     2
5    1  Jun-21     0          2     2
6    1  Jul-21     1          3     3
7    1  Aug-21     1          3     3
8    1  Sep-21     0          3     3
9    1  Oct-21     1          4     4
10   2  Jan-21     1          0     0
11   2  Feb-21     1          0     0
12   2  Mar-21     0          0     0
13   2  Apr-21     1          1     1
14   2  May-21     0          1     1
15   2  Jun-21     1          2     2
16   2  Jul-21     0          2     2
17   2  Jun-21     0          2     2
18   2  Jul-21     1          3     3
19   2  Aug-21     0          3     3
20   2  Sep-21     0          3     3
21   3  Jan-21     1          0     0
22   3  Feb-21     1          0     0
23   3  Mar-21     0          0     0
24   3  Apr-21     1          1     1
25   3  May-21     0          1     1
26   3  Jun-21     0          1     1
27   3  Jul-21     0          1     1
28   3  Aug-21     1          2     2
29   3  Sep-21     0          2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option. My data is slightly different from your data as for ID = 2, June & July has been repeated in your data. I removed that. But with repeated data also this code will work as it's not considering date while calculating `col2`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'period': ['21-Jan', '21-Feb', '21-Mar', '21-Apr', '21-May', '21-Jun', '21-Jul', '21-Aug', '21-Sep',
                   '21-Oct',
                   '21-Jan', '21-Feb', '21-Mar', '21-Apr', '21-May', '21-Jun', '21-Jul',
                   '21-Aug', '21-Sep',
                   '21-Jan', '21-Feb', '21-Mar', '21-Apr', '21-May', '21-Jun', '21-Jul', '21-Aug', '21-Sep'],
        'col1': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        'col2': [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Detect changes from 0 to 1
df['change'] = (df['col1'] - df.groupby('Id')['col1'].shift(fill_value=0)) == 1

# Compute the new col2 values
df['col2_generated'] = df.groupby('Id')['change'].transform('cumsum').astype(int)

print(df[['Id', 'period', 'col1', 'col2', 'col2_generated']])

Id  period  col1  col2  col2_generated
0    1  21-Jan     0     0               0
1    1  21-Feb     1     1               1
2    1  21-Mar     0     1               1
3    1  21-Apr     0     1               1
4    1  21-May     1     2               2
5    1  21-Jun     0     2               2
6    1  21-Jul     1     3               3
7    1  21-Aug     1     3               3
8    1  21-Sep     0     3               3
9    1  21-Oct     1     4               4
10   2  21-Jan     0     0               0
11   2  21-Feb     1     1               1
12   2  21-Mar     0     1               1
13   2  21-Apr     1     2               2
14   2  21-May     0     2               2
15   2  21-Jun     0     2               2
16   2  21-Jul     1     3               3
17   2  21-Aug     0     3               3
18   2  21-Sep     0     3               3
19   3  21-Jan     0     0               0
20   3  21-Feb     1     1               1
21   3  21-Mar     0     1               1
22   3  21-Apr     0     1               1
23   3  21-May     0     1               1
24   3  21-Jun     1     2               2
25   3  21-Jul     0     2               2
26   3  21-Aug     0     2               2
27   3  21-Sep     1     3               3
```